# How to predict hourly data

Tags: r, date, datetime, time-series, prediction

I am a beginner and would like some help with an assignment. 
I have data in an excel file that represent click per hour by browser.
The data looks like something like this :

```
        v11         v12         v13         v14               date
6.111111111 0.066666667 3.488888889 0.155555556 12-12-2016 0:00:00
```

There is data until beginning of 2017 and I am supposed to predict values after the last date.

I have tried created a time series (ts,start,end, frequency) in order to use arima to estimate future values but for some reasons the date appear wrong. I end up with a start date of 1992 even though i specified 2016-12-12 (see below)

```
#Load data from Excel file
data1 <- read.xlsx("Training data set.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1,colIndex=1)
data1 <- data.matrix(data1)
v1 <- c(data1)
v1.timeseries <- ts(v1, start = c(2016-12-12,1), frequency = 24)
print(v1.timeseries)
Time Series:
Start = c(1992, 1) 
End = c(2020, 24) 
Frequency = 24 
[1]  92.86667  80.13333  76.37778  91.80000 119.06667 151.40000 176.57778
```

Then I thought that a regression would be a better idea but I am not able to transform the date column into the yyyy-mm-dd time that R reads. 
I have looked online and haven't been able to figure out how to set up my data in R in order to make predictions.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Please check the syntax for using `start` in `ts`  It might be `ts(rnorm(100), start = c(2016, 12, 12), frequency = 24)`

Comment: Also, you can format your time like `as.POSIXct("12-12-2016 0:00:00", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` for example assuming you have day/mon/year - otherwise reverse the day/month specifiers as expected.

Comment: if you want an easy way of dealing with virtually *any* date format for the rest of your career in R then look into the `lubridate` package. not that the solutions above won't solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

**

> I am not able to transform the date column into the yyyy-mm-dd time
>   that R reads

**

Suppose this is your text file (trial.txt) as shown below,

```
    v11 v12 v13 v14 date
6.111111111 0.066666667 3.488888889 0.155555556  12-12-2016 13:30:20
```

Read the text file in R

```
df = read.table("trial.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

> df
       v11        v12      v13       v14                 date
1 6.111111 0.06666667 3.488889 0.1555556  12-12-2016 13:30:20
> class(df$date)
[1] "factor"
> df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
> class(df$date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> df$date
[1] "2016-12-12 13:30:20 IST"
> df
       v11        v12      v13       v14                date
1 6.111111 0.06666667 3.488889 0.1555556 2016-12-12 13:30:20
```

The above example converts the date column in to the yyyy-mm-dd time format that can be read by R.